# How to handle user action

Tags: c#, node.js, botframework

I want to handle User actions in Bot framework using c#. I am displaying some Inputs as choices to users. Here user may not want any of the choices. SO they can directly type in some commands to Exit. If user Types Exit, instead of selecting choices (Exit is not listed in choice), i need to handle the exit. By default Bot will not allow to enter something not listed.

Hope this can be done by Node JS ([Handle User Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-actions?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)). I want to achieve the below same functionality.

Can someone assist me on this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If user Types Exit, instead of selecting choices (Exit is not listed in choice), i need to handle the exit. By default Bot will not allow to enter something not listed.

You can try to implement [global message handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-global-handlers?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) that execute code whenever the user replies to the conversation with specific word `Exit`. The following code snippet is for your reference.

***GlobalMessageHandlersBotModule:***

```
public class GlobalMessageHandlersBotModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);

        builder
            .Register(c => new ExitScorable(c.Resolve<IDialogTask>()))
            .As<IScorable<IActivity, double>>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

***ExitScorable:***

```
public class ExitScorable : ScorableBase<IActivity, string, double>
{
    private readonly IDialogTask task;

    public ExitScorable(IDialogTask task)
    {
        SetField.NotNull(out this.task, nameof(task), task);
    }

    protected override async Task<string> PrepareAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var message = activity as IMessageActivity;

        if (message != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.Text))
        {
            if (message.Text.ToLower().Equals("exit", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return message.Text;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected override bool HasScore(IActivity item, string state)
    {
        return state != null;
    }

    protected override double GetScore(IActivity item, string state)
    {
        return 1.0;
    }

    protected override async Task PostAsync(IActivity item, string state, CancellationToken token)
    {
        this.task.Reset();
    }
    protected override Task DoneAsync(IActivity item, string state, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Han, Found the global message handler in the below link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-global-handlers?view=azure-bot-service-3.0. Hope the link can be helpful for someone.